# Difficulty exporting data from R with write.csv and append

Tags: r, export

I would be delighted and most grateful if anyone can explain to me why I am having a problem exporting some data from a function which extracts coefficients from a linear model.  I have hundreds to do so I’m hoping to build a loop to handle it but have fallen at an earlier hurdle.
I am using methods borrowed from someone much smarter at this stuff:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-ecology/2008-May/000062.html
The relevant bits (data creation, the function and finally my attempt to export my data are below) but firstly I will mention that the data, “export”, is exported to the experiment.csv file as a single COLUMN.  I am told that the Append property of the write.table function only works with rows.  Consequently it overwrites previous runs of the same sets of commands rather than successfully appending it.
The error messages are of the form below: (they are all the same, one for each piece of information).
**Warning messages:
1: In write.csv(export, file = "experiment.csv", append = TRUE, quote = TRUE,  :
  attempt to set 'append' ignored**

```
#DATA CREATION
# create an empty list
mod <- list()
# start a loop for create 5 objects of class 'lm'
for (i in 1:5) {
  x <- rnorm(i*10)
  y <- rnorm(i*10)
  mod[[paste("run",i,sep="")]] <- lm(y ~ x)
}
# FUNCTION TO EXTRACT DATA
myFun <-
  function(lm)
  {
    out <- c(lm$coefficients[1],
             lm$coefficients[2],
             length(lm$model$y),
             summary(lm)$coefficients[2,2],
             pf(summary(lm)$fstatistic[1], summary(lm)$fstatistic[2],
                summary(lm)$fstatistic[3], lower.tail = FALSE),
             summary(lm)$r.squared)
    names(out) <- c("intercept","slope","n","slope.SE","p.value","r.squared")
    return(out)}
# FAILED ATTEMPT TO EXPORT
export <-myFun(mod$run1)
write.csv(export, file = "experiment.csv", append = TRUE, quote = TRUE, sep = " ",
          eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = FALSE,
          col.names = FALSE, qmethod = c("escape", "double"),
          fileEncoding = "")
```

Comment: If you aren't even writing a comma separated file, then you probably should use `write.table` rather than `write.csv`. The latter doesn't allow the `append=` option for whatever reason. You can't append columns to a file. You can only append rows.

Comment: my guess is `write.csv` doesn't allow `append` because then it would have to check for column matching

Comment: Also should be noted this isn't an error message, it's a warning. It still did something, it's just warning you it's probably not what you meant.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I had been advised (wrongly) to try write.csv when I'd had earlier problems.  Now I just tried it again with write.table and it does append the data, albeit the data goes in as a column which is a bit odd.  I'm not really all that bothered about that though - it's easy enough for me to transpose the data in Excel if I want to. Thanks for pointing out that it was a warning not an error message; best to get these things straight :).  Cheers.